# How to make the iterated output in the same line?

Tags: freemarker

I want to generate some java code using freemarker, that is to generate parameters for a method.Say I have a method named doIt, which needs some parameter name and their class names, I will give the template a param named paramList.I define a macro directive , iterate the parameters list,but consequently each parameter occupies a row. My template code is as below:

```
<#macro paramList plist>
   <#if plist??>
       <#list plist as p>
           ${p.javaType?substring(2)} ${p.name} <#if p_has_next>, </#if>
       </#list>
   </#if>
</#macro>
doIt(<@paramList plist=params/>)
```

The running result is :

```
doIt(           int end , 
           String endDate , 
           String evtCode , 
           int evtNo , 
           String giftCode , 
           int start , 
           String startDate 
)
```

How to make all the parameters output appear in the same row. I know I can write the list directive logic in the same row to avoid line breaking ,but if there are other logic too, it will get too long to read and understand after a while.
 The format I want is :

```
doIt(int end , String endDate, String evtCode , int evtNo , String giftCode , int start , String startDate)
```

Answer (score 7):

Put a `<#t>` after the innermost `</#if>`. (See http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_t.html#ref.directive.t)

Comment: Wonderful, I put a <#> after "${p.javaType?substring(2)} ${p.name} <#if p_has_next>, </#if>", then it gives me the result I expect exactly. You did me a big favor, thanks. Turns out line breaking is part of concept of  white-blank in freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for you to do it there would be to change your code like this:

```
<#macro paramList plist>
   <#if plist??>
        <#list plist as p>${p.javaType?substring(2)} ${p.name} <#if p_has_next>, </#if></#list>
   </#if>
</#macro>
doIt(<@paramList plist=params/>)
```

That is, make the list all inline.  It's harder to read, but it will keep your white space characters that you need (i.e. the spaces).